# How to run Telegram iOS source code on Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, compilation, xcode6, telegram

I am attempting to compile and run iOS telegram source code from https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram. Even though the source seems alright and builds successfully on Xcode 6.1, I can not see anything on iPhone simulator?! It does not run! What should I do? I need to customise telegram source code for my project.

Best,

Comment: Why you don't use Xcode 8.2?

Comment: the source code was from to 1  or 2 years ago, so changing my Xcode does not have any effect?!